# module fbprophet incompatible for python 3.7.* and higher?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science

Has anyone successfully tried installing fbprophet on anaconda?
When i try to install it, i get an incompatibility error.
I'd be very surprised if there isn't fbprophet for python 3.7 +

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- fbprophet -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked
 for.When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is s
omehow not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda wil
l not change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly sp
ecify that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There is a version for python 3.7, and I am able to install successfully. Can you try to use conda-forge and defaults channels together and see if it is available?

```
conda install fbprophet -c conda-forge -c defaults --override-channels
```

I had problems when using -c conda-forge only, so i suspect the necessary compatible packages are spread across different channels/locations.

These are the versions that are compatible with Python 3.7:

```
(ds_tensorflow) >>conda search fbprophet -c conda-forge -c defaults --override-channels | grep py37
    fbprophet                        0.5  py37h6538335_0  conda-forge
    fbprophet                        0.5  py37h6538335_1  conda-forge
    fbprophet                        0.5  py37h6538335_2  conda-forge
    fbprophet                        0.5  py37h6538335_3  conda-forge
    fbprophet                        0.6  py37h6538335_0  conda-forge
```

Comment: can you try to create a brand new conda environment with only python 3.7 and fbprophet?
`conda create --name py37_fbp fbprophet -c conda-forge -c defaults --override-channels`. If this works, then there is a problem with the environment you are using, not with fbprophet or python3.7 in general

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this. I downloaded the fbprophet zipped package for Windows from the github repo, extracted the contents and launched anaconda, cd to condabin, then ran pip install specifying the path to the package folder.

Hope this helps anyone stuck in the same situation !!!

Regards,

Ochen